# Jquery Drop down list function to return and keep selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have what is a stupidly simply drop down list, when a selection is made it appends the value seen in the below list to the URL to do a sort, while this works I am missing a piece of the puzzle as it does not retain the selection. The onchange forces a refresh of the page, while the value is still passed into the URL and remains to the user it may still be apparent that they have not made a selection. So I am looking at perhaps using Jquery as a function in the onchange rather than a redirect that is being used now, but I have no idea where to start as I am pretty new to this...

```
 <select id="Selection" class="sorter" onchange="location=this.options[[this.selectedIndex]].value" style="float:right;margin-right:8px;">
   <option value="">Sort by</option>
   <option value="?orderby=0">Code</option>
   <option value="?orderby=1">Title A-Z</option>
   <option value="?orderby=2">Title Z-A</option>
   <option value="?orderby=3">Brand</option>
   <option value="?orderby=4">Lowest price</option>
   <option value="?orderby=5">Highest price</option>
   <option value="?orderby=6">Lowest Quantity</option>
   <option value="?orderby=7">Highest Quantity</option>
 </select>
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated...

Comment: show jQuery code or jsfiddle

Comment: I don't have any this is literally all I have, and need help in getting something that might be a workable solution. I am trying to modify this based on a CMS selection.

Comment: Aren't u using any Server side language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ans. to ur Question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function($) {
    $.QueryString = (function(a) {
        if (a == "") return {};
        var b = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
        {
            var p=a[i].split('=');
            if (p.length != 2) continue;
            b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
        return b;
    })(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'))
})(jQuery);
var qstr=$.QueryString["orderby"];
alert(qstr);
//$("#Selection").prop("selectedIndex", qstr); 
</script>

 <select id="Selection" class="sorter" onchange="location=this.options[[this.selectedIndex]].value" style="float:right;margin-right:8px;">
   <option  id=1 value="">Sort by</option>
   <option  id=2  value="?orderby=1">Code</option>
   <option  id=3 value="?orderby=2">Title A-Z</option>
   <option  id=4 value="?orderby=3">Title Z-A</option>
   <option  id=5 value="?orderby=4">Brand</option>
   <option  id=6 value="?orderby=5">Lowest price</option>
   <option  id=7 value="?orderby=6">Highest price</option>
   <option  id=8 value="?orderby=7">Lowest Quantity</option>
   <option  id=9 value="?orderby=8">Highest Quantity</option>
 </select>

<script>$("#Selection").prop("selectedIndex", qstr); 
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its adding a pop-up and the page refresh is not working anymore, you can see for yourself: http://protoys.gentex.com.au/Products/Catalogue.aspx you will find the sort at under the menu toward the right, before products

Comment: remove alert box then to remove popup ,its easy.

Comment: Dude, you didnt include , onchange event. USE like above : onchange="location=this.options[[this.selectedIndex]].value"